# How can I update date of datetime field with mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, date, datetime

I'm working on a project about a social networking site and I want the user to change his date of birth. I have a table user with user's information (email, birthdate,etc).    My code:

```
< form action="editController.jsp" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
< select name="day">
   < option value="day">Day< /option> 
   < % for(int i=1; i<=31; i++){ %> 
       < option value="<%= i %>"><%= i %> < /option>
   <%} %>   
< /select>
```

Here user choose a day. Then in editController.jsp :

```
String day = request.getParameter("day"); 
Ismgroup9DAO dao = new Ismgroup9DAO();
dao.open(); 
dao.editDay(email, day);
```

In my editDay method I don't know what should I write in the query so as birthdate to be updated.

Comment: that would update everybody who has a date equalling 2014-01-08. You might want to show your html for how they choose a date and your current query. It's most likely not this snippet

Comment: <form action="editController.jsp" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
     <select name="day">
     <option value="day">Day</option>
<%
     for(int i=1; i<=31; i++){
%>    
      <option value="<%= i %>"><%= i %></option>
<%  
     }
%>    
     </select>

Here they choose a day. Then in editController.jsp : 

String day = request.getParameter("day");
Ismgroup9DAO dao = new Ismgroup9DAO();
dao.open();
dao.editDay(email, day);

In my editDay method I don't know what should I write in the query so as birthdate to be updated.

Comment: you should update your question and put the code there. As you can see it is very difficult to read in a comment